# Differences when starting selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar by double click vs command line java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Tags: java, selenium, cmd

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar to run some automated tests with maven.

Everything works fine when starting the Selenium server by double-clicking on that jar file. 
I see that this starts javaw.exe (javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*).

When starting the Selenium server using CMD `start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`, I get the following error:

```
Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

I think this is related to variables inherited by CMD cause even if I change the command to

```
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\bin\javaw.exe -jar src\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Can someone explain what are the differences between running the jar by double click vs from command line?
Thanks

Comment: I think it should not even run in case of double click because you need to provide the driver file firefox driver(gecko) or chrome driver binary path as an argument while running the selenium standalone jar.

Comment: it works when starting with double click; I've added -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" in the command line and still getting the same error